QGIS raster georeferencing. Is it possible to get a table with a coordinate and a pixel corresponding to it on the ORIGINAL raster?
I have an image of some area (raster) and I need to, knowing coordinate, get pixel on that raster. But if I will use raster georeferencig, I'll get a distorted GeoTIFF. Can I get this data from GeoTIFF? Perfectly will be a table with coordinate, old raster pixel position and new georeferenced raster pixel position.
